# Why spearmanr function's output changes when the input representation is changed without changing the order?

Tags: python, scipy, correlation

The following code computes the spearman rank correlation between two ordered lists:

```
from scipy.stats import spearmanr
a1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
b1 = [0, 1, 3, 2, 5]
print(spearmanr(a1,b1).correlation) # the result is 0.9
```

and the result is 0.9. But when I represent the vectors without changing the orders, the correlation is changed to 0.5:

```
a2 = ['ESR1', 'TBC1D9', 'SCUBE2', 'EVL', 'NAT2']
b2 = ['ESR1', 'TBC1D9', 'EVL', 'SCUBE2', 'CIRBP']
print(spearmanr(a2,b2).correlation) # the result is 0.5
```

I wonder why the result changes even though the orders are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spearman's rank correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) is based on the ranking of the inputs.  It assumes that the input variables are ordinal, that is, they have a natural ordering.  If you pass in strings, that ordering is the alphabetical order of the string.  The orderings are not the same for your two versions of the data:

```
In [16]: a1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

In [17]: b1 = [0, 1, 3, 2, 5]

In [18]: a2 = ['ESR1', 'TBC1D9', 'SCUBE2', 'EVL', 'NAT2']

In [19]: b2 = ['ESR1', 'TBC1D9', 'EVL', 'SCUBE2', 'CIRBP']

In [20]: from scipy.stats import rankdata

In [21]: rankdata(a1)
Out[21]: array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.])

In [22]: rankdata(b1)
Out[22]: array([1., 2., 4., 3., 5.])

In [23]: rankdata(a2)
Out[23]: array([1., 5., 4., 2., 3.])

In [24]: rankdata(b2)
Out[24]: array([2., 5., 3., 4., 1.])
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought that `spearmanr` takes the ordered list as input, for example, if the input list is `a`, then `a[0]` is the element with the highest rank, and so on. But according to your answer, it seems that it takes some sort of the position of each element. Am I right?

Comment: It is, in effect, the Pearson correlation coefficient of the *ranks* of the inputs.